# Getting URL of referencing page Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, jakarta-ee

How can i get the Url of previous page that I used to reference to servlet? I know i can use get Header "reference" but I want to use HTTP Session API. Is it possible doing it with HTTP Session API?

```
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("theURL", request.getHeader("referer"));
out.println(session.getAttribute("theURL"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

See http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/webapp/faq.xtp